# Unsupervised Ranking

Tags: unsupervised-learning, ranking

Assume we have N data points like

```
data = [(x1, y1, z1), (x2, y2, z2),....., (x_N, y_N, z_N)].
```

I am looking for unsupervised ranking algorithms. The thumb of rules for higher ranking are, higher x and y, but lower z. But high x, high y and low z may have competitive contribution for ranking.

For example,

```
 D = [(10, 500, 0), (15, 200, 2), (1, 10, 20), (10, 550, 40)]
```

We may have ranking like `(10, 500, 0) > (15, 200, 2) > (10, 550, 40) > (1, 10, 20)`, or `(15, 200, 2) > (10, 500, 0) > (1, 10, 20) > (10, 550, 40)`, depending on model.

Does everyone have any ideas, what type of unsupervised machine learning algorithms are possibly useful for such problem? Thanks!